# mySQL using where on newly created column

Tags: mysql, sql, average, where-clause, having-clause

So, I think this is fairly simple, but I am messing something up.

I have the query

```
SELECT AVG(price), food_type
FROM instructor
GROUP BY food_type
```

Which produces this:

```
Price | food_type |
2.25 | Drink     |
1.50 | Candy     |
3    | Soup      |
```

And I am trying to return all prices over 2$

So I want:

```
Price | food_type |
2.25 | Drink     |
3    | Soup      |
```

It seems like it should be as simple as

```
SELECT AVG(price), food_type
FROM instructor
WHERE AVG(price) > 2
GROUP BY food_type
```

But I can't get this to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate function in SQL WHERE-Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319183/aggregate-function-in-sql-where-clause)

Comment: in case anyone facing a similar issue for a non-aggregate function do check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726887/how-to-use-new-created-column-in-where-column-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate function in the `where` clause. Instead, you need `having`:

```
SELECT AVG(price), food_type
FROM instructor
GROUP BY food_type
HAVING AVG(price) > 2
```

In MySQL, you can also refer to an alias in the `HAVING` clause (this is an extension to standard SQL):

```
SELECT AVG(price) avg_price, food_type
FROM instructor
GROUP BY food_type
HAVING avg_price > 2
```